# How to know that jquery is executed successfully and now i can trigger any other action

Tags: javascript

I am doing a module in which jquery plugin is installed on webpage and being executed in javascript.
I am having trouble in finding whether the jquery have been executed full successfully or is still in working.... 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some code, your question is too vague

Comment: You'll have to be elaborate...

Comment: As long as you include the script for the jQuery plugin before your script, you should be fine

Comment: please elaborate , what is it working on and you want to check if it finished successfully exactly  ? and add your code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

By running your code off a handler such as in

$(document).ready(handler)

you can know it's been called by jQuery after jQuery was loaded.

Comment: thanks wulf solter.... it worked for me